# pycadf error while installing OpenStack Liberty via devstack -Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: python, openstack, devstack

I am trying to install OpenStack using devstack, but i get this error :

[image]

It seems to me that pycadf is a library required by keystone. I tryed to install it by this command : `sudo get install python-pycadf` but still getting the same problem.
Did any one had the same problem ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use stable and fresh pypi mirrors, look up a suitable one for you from here: http://www.pypi-mirrors.org/

by default: http://pypi.python.org/simple

openstack ci uses: http://pypi.iad.openstack.org/simple

for China mainland, try this: http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple